# UserForm1 not being detected as a Normal User but yes as a Administrator when Logged as such

Tags: excel, vba

I have set some permissions, so normal users can´t see all the sheets on excel and only the admin can view all (Code below) 
When I log as Admin and i click on the command button that is set on the page "Supervisores", it works fine. If i do it with a Normal user, it says the following error

> object variable or with object not set

and marks `Load UserForm1` on the macro_click below. I can´t find what is wrong, or what is missing. I need a big hand, because some days before it worked fine, but now it broke...

The button with the macro its set on the page where the button its displayed. And the login code on a userform1.

```
Private Sub btnEntrar_Click()
    'Declare the variables
    Dim AddData As Range, AddData2 As Range, AddData3 As Range, Current As Range
    Dim Code As Variant
    Dim PName As Variant, AName As Variant, UName As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet, ws5 As Worksheet, ws6 As Worksheet
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim TitleStr As String
    Dim msg As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim LogsUsuarios As Worksheet


    'Set the pages variables
    Set ws = Worksheets("Inicio")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Supervisores")
    Set ws3 = Worksheets("Registros")
    Set ws4 = Worksheets("Ingreso")
    Set ws5 = Worksheets("LogsUsuarios")
    Set ws6 = Worksheets("LookupList")
    Set LogsUsuarios = Hoja6

    'Variables
    user = Me.txtUser.Value
    Code = Me.txtPass.Value
    TitleStr = "Password check"
    result = 0
    Set Current = ws4.Range("M3")

    'Error handler
    On Error GoTo errHandler:

    'Destination location for login storage
    Set AddData = ws5.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Set AddData2 = ws5.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Set AddData3 = ws5.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'Check the login and passcode for the Administrator
    If user <> "" And Not IsNumeric(user) And Code <> "" Then
        For Each AName In ws4.Range("R4:R6")
            'If AName = Code Then 'Use this for passcode text
            If AName = Code And AName.Offset(0, -1) = user Then ' Puede usar texto Y números
                MsgBox "Inicio como Administrador de: " & user

                'record user login
                AddData.Value = user
                AddData.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
                'Add usernmae to the worksheet
                Current.Value = user
                'Change variable if the condition is meet
                result = 1
                'Unload the form
                ws.Visible = True   'Cambiar para que lo tome de la tabla de permisos y no manual como ahora, usar el cod de abajo
                ws2.Visible = True
                ws3.Visible = True
                ws4.Visible = True
                ws5.Visible = True
                ws6.Visible = True
                Unload Me

            'sort the Registros by "Último Ingreso"
            Hoja6.Select
            With LogsUsuarios
                .Range("C4:C1000").Sort Key1:=Range("C4"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess
            End With
            ws4.Select 'Dirigirme a la pagina "Ingreso"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next AName
    End If

        'Check user login with loop
        If user <> "" And Not IsNumeric(user) And Code <> "" Then
            For Each UName In ws4.Range("R11:R19")
                'If UName = Code Then 'Use this for passcode text
                If UName = Code And UName.Offset(0, -1) = user Then ' Puede usar texto Y números
                    MsgBox "Ingreso satisfactorio para: " & user

                'record user login
                If user = "MCARULO" Then
                AddData2.Value = user
                AddData2.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now

                'record user login
                ElseIf user = "BRAVO" Then
                AddData3.Value = user
                AddData3.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now

                Else
                AddData.Value = user
                AddData.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
                End If

                'Add user to the worksheet
                Current.Value = user

                Set PName = Hoja2.Range("E:E").Find(What:=user, LookIn:=xlValues)

                'unhide worksheet for user
                If PName.Offset(0, 2) = "Inicio" Then
                'Set ws = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 2).Value)
                ws.Visible = True
                End If

                If PName.Offset(0, 3) = "Supervisores" Then
                'Set ws2 = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 3).Value)
                ws2.Visible = True
                ws2.Select 'Se cambia la pantalla a este para los Supervisores
                'Inicio Automático el Multi
                'InicioSuperv
                End If

                If PName.Offset(0, 4) = "Registros" Then
                'Set ws3 = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 3).Value)
                ws3.Visible = True
                End If

                If PName.Offset(0, 5) = "Ingreso" Then
                'Set ws4 = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 4).Value)
                ws4.Visible = True
                ws4.Select 'Se cambia la pantalla a este para RRHH
                End If

                If PName.Offset(0, 6) = "LogsUsuarios" Then
                'Set ws5 = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 5).Value)
                ws5.Visible = True
                End If

                If PName.Offset(0, 7) = "LookupList" Then
                'Set ws5 = Worksheets(PName.Offset(0, 5).Value)
                ws6.Visible = True
                End If

                'show sheet tab if hidden
                ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True

                'Change variable if the condition is meet
                result = 1

                'Unload the form
                Unload Me

                'sort the Registros by "Último Ingreso"
                Hoja6.Select
                With LogsUsuarios
                .Range("C4:C1000").Sort Key1:=Range("C4"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess
                End With

                'Esconde la Hoja Nuevamente
                ws5.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next UName
    End If
```

```
Private Sub cmdMacro2_Click() 'Inicia en el Inicio Gral

Load UserForm1: UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0: UserForm1.Show vbModeless

If UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0 Then
'Desactiva los botones del inicio que no correspondan para los supervisores}
UserForm1.inicioNR.Enabled = False
UserForm1.inicioBD.Enabled = False

'Desabilita las páginas que no pueden utilizar los supervisores
'UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Enabled = False
UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(1).Enabled = False
UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Enabled = False

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the error point to a section of `Load UserForm1: UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0: UserForm1.Show vbModeless` or the entire line, may be best to break into lines and see which one has the error/

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I break it like this: `Load UserForm1: _
UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0: _
UserForm1.Show _
vbModeless` And the error is shown on **Load UserForm1**

Comment: Have you tried them on a separate line each ?  Is there code in the forms startup also?

Comment: I don´t understand how to seperate by line each. And in the startup i do not have more code.

Comment: A new line for each statement, rather than statement1:statement2:statement3

Comment: i did that and does not work. The problem its on the "record users login". I will try to modify it and see what can work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the worksheet where the userform1 was stored and seems all working fine now. Here is the final code:

```
Private Sub cmdMacro2_Click() 'Inicia en el Inicio Gral

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registros")

    With Registros
        Load UserForm1:
        UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0:
        UserForm1.Show vbModeless

        If UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0 Then
            'Desactiva los botones del inicio que no correspondan para los supervisores}
            UserForm1.inicioNR.Enabled = False
            UserForm1.inicioBD.Enabled = False

            'Desabilita las páginas que no pueden utilizar los supervisores
            'UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Enabled = False
            UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(1).Enabled = False
            UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Enabled = False

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```